# Why R code with `{}` is faster than that with `()`?

Tags: r

Why is the R code with `{}` in general faster than the one with `()`, example below ?

```
n=10000000
w1=numeric(n)
w2=numeric(n)
r=rnorm(n)


t1=Sys.time()
for(i in 1:n)
w1[i]=((r[i]^2))*(1*1)
t1-Sys.time()


t1=Sys.time()
for(i in 1:n)
w2[i]={{r[i]^2}}*{1*1}
t1-Sys.time()
```

Comment: It's not for me, using R-2.15.2 on 64-bit Linux. Please provide output from `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: check the [blog of Radford Neal](http://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/two-surpising-things-about-r/)

Comment: I'd also appreciate a real world example of where the differences identified above (which I can't reproduce BTW) would make a tangible difference in how you'd approach a task.

Comment: The linked blog of Radford Neal provides examples and explanations.

Comment: Another 'tip' to reduce fractions of milliseconds: use `**` instead of `^`

Comment: It's funny, though, that both `'{'` and `'('` parse as `call` objects, with primitive functions. The difference must be in the C code.

Comment: @Lukas look at Ferdinand.kraft answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**baptiste** already linked *Radford Neal*'s blog in the comments.
But since the SE people don't like links to external sites, let me quote an interesting comment of the author himself (comment 33):

> Yes, parentheses are still slower than curly brackets in R 2.13.1, and in the latest R 2.14.1, though not by as much as before (a patch I suggested to reduce general overhead in built-in functions was incorported in later releases, which reduced this difference).
>
> There’s no good reason for parentheses to be slower. I suggested another change (to just a couple lines of code) that would speed up parentheses. Luke Tierney responded that this patch should on no account be incorporated into R, on the basis that **parentheses are an operator just like sqrt**, and that there should therefore be nothing in the code implementing parentheses that departs from how operators like sqrt are implemented.

Knowing that, `( )` appears to be an operator - much like a function doing basically nothing -
while `{ }` is a language construct.
The parentheses `( )` incorporate some overhead code common to all operators which is actually of no need for them.

Comment: This answer is incorrect: `{` are *also* an operator in R nowadays, not a language construct! And like `(`, it can be overloaded. It’s possible that this changed since the comment (and this answer) were written, however.

Answer (score 5):

Lukas answered the question nicely, but here are some timings on the overhead for those interested (which can be effectively removed by vectorising your code).

```
brace <- function(n){
w1=numeric(n)
w2=numeric(n)
r=rnorm(n)
for(i in 1:n)
w1[i]=((r[i]^2))*(1*1)
}


curly <- function(n){
w1=numeric(n)
w2=numeric(n)
r=rnorm(n)
for(i in 1:n)
w2[i]={{r[i]^2}}*{1*1}
}



microbenchmark( curly(1e5) , brace(1e5) , times = 50 ) 
Unit: milliseconds
         expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 curly(1e+05) 311.4245 318.8916 324.1990 335.0928 400.8555    50
 brace(1e+05) 315.5428 323.8860 328.7982 350.7268 406.5785    50
```

Around a 5 millisecond difference at 1e5 loop lengths. So let's remove the loops:

```
braceV <- function(n){
w1=numeric(n)
w2=numeric(n)
r=rnorm(n)
w1=((r^2))*(1*1)
}


curlyV <- function(n){
w1=numeric(n)
w2=numeric(n)
r=rnorm(n)
w2={{r^2}}*{1*1}
}

microbenchmark( curlyV(1e5) , braceV(1e5) , times = 50 )
Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min       lq    median       uq      max neval
 curlyV(1e+05) 9.014361 9.284532  9.666867 10.81317 37.82510    50
 braceV(1e+05) 9.029408 9.373773 10.293302 10.83487 37.76596    50
```

The difference is now around ~0.5 milliseconds.