# Why do parentheses slow down my program in R

Tags: r

I caught some redundant parentheses in my friend's code and it really slowed down the execution time. If there any explanation for this. Please check out this example code

Python is also a (quesi) interpreted language and doesn't suffer from this program.

```
# 0.370 seconds
x <- 0
while (x < 100000) {
    10
    x = x + 1
}
```

```
# 0.743 seconds
x <- 0
while (x < 100000) {
    ((((((((((10))))))))))
    x = x + 1
}
```

Comment: You can check [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/speeding-up-parentheses-and-lots-more-in-r/)

Comment: I wrote a book that was only 2 pages long.  When I added 1000 blank pages before the 2 that had the actual content it took readers longer to read.  Why?

Comment: @Dason this explanation does not explain why it does not occur in Python or Javascript.

Comment: This was a good read too [curly brackets answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15927157/9555388)

Comment: If extra parens "really slowed down the execution", your friend wrote some seriously inefficient R code. The extra parens are the least of the problems.

Comment: this is an interesting theoretical question (I think it could be considered a dupe of the question [@HectorHaffenden referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926553/why-r-code-with-is-faster-than-that-with/15927157#15927157)), but I'm not going to hit it with my golden dupe-hammer because I'm not 100% sure. Like the other commenters, I would be quite surprised if it was a *practical* problem ...

Comment: I see no measurable difference between code with and without parens R version is 3.5. R versions since 3.4 include JIT compilation, which should optimize the loop code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [akrun's comment](https://www.r-bloggers.com/speeding-up-parentheses-and-lots-more-in-r/) talks about `R v2.11.1`, things haven't really changed.

The help for [?paren](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Paren.html) (Parentheses and Braces), says that unlike some other languages parentheses and braces are primitive functions in R. Which means that when ever you write `a <- 1`, the 1 is just a 1. However, if you write `a <- (1)`, the 1 is inside a function.

Therefore, if you'll run even simple evaluations, parentheses will take more time (as you evaluate a function and a number).

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark("simple" = {a <- 1},
                      "parentheses" = {
                        a <- (1)})

Unit: nanoseconds
        expr min  lq mean median  uq   max neval cld
      simple   0 100   89    100 100   700   100   a
 parentheses 100 100  310    200 200 16000   100   a

sessionInfo()

R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```